# Active Admin resources missing template after upgrade to v1.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Document do
  controller do
    def create
      create!
    end
  end
end
```

This was working fine in ActiveAdmin 0.6.6 however after upgrading to v1.1.0 it is unable to find the create template and `ActionView::MissingTemplate` is thrown:

```
Missing template documents/create, active_admin/resource/create, active_admin/base/create, inherited_resources/base/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/ent/Desktop/Apps/vent/app/views"
  * "/Users/ent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views"
  * "/Users/ent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/kaminari-core-1.1.1/app/views"
  * "/Users/ent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/devise_cas_authenticatable-1.10.4/app/views"
  * "/Users/ent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views"
```

Is there anything that has changed since the upgrade that I am missing?
I have tried the following versions of active admin: 1.0.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3 however they all have the same error. Downgrading back to 0.6.6 seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: What error (if any) do you get when you remove the complete ``controller do`` block? Also try replacing the call to ``create!`` with ``super``.

Comment: I just tried both, they both result in exactly the same error

Comment: Environment: Ruby 2.5.5 & Rails 4.2.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `create` does not typically have it's own view.

To fix it, you can use this construct and instruct controller action what to do on success / failure of the create action. In this example, on success we will redirect to the resource detail, on failure we will render the `new` view (as most likely the validation of the resource failed and user needs update and resubmit the form):

```
controller do
  def create
    super do |success, failure|
      success.html { redirect_to your_resource_path(resource), notice: "#{resource.name} has been created." }
      failure.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I gues the path helper would be ```admin_document_path(resource)```.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I have modified my create method to this and it finally works!